# Monit on EC2 - Monit works but it doesn't monitor any service

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, monit

I have a ubuntu 14.04 instance on amazon, I've installed monit with some simple configuration files but it seems like it doesn't monitor them. I have installed monit a couple of times in other servers (with ubuntu 14.04) and I have used exactly the same configuration fiels without any problem.

Is there something which I have to check with amazon? Monit seems to run but it doesn't monitor any service. The services are: nginx, redis, ssh and some custom applications. Can this be a permission problem? Any idea?

**Update:**
I am adding the config files for completeness. I've tried different combinations and even to have only one config file but it didn't worked and as I said the config files are working perfectly all together in the same OS, same service and similar way of installing it on another server outside of AWS. They are super simple and of course I have checked the paths and the PIDs and they are working, so I guess the problem is somewhere else and maybe it has to do with amazon standar ubuntu installation and some bad default.

**Redis**

```
check process redis-server
  with pidfile "/var/run/redis/redis-server.pid"
  start program = "/etc/init.d/redis-server start"
  stop program = "/etc/init.d/redis-server stop"
```

**nginx**

```
check process nginx with pidfile /var/run/nginx.pid
  start program = "/etc/init.d/nginx start"
  stop program = "/etc/init.d/nginx stop"
```

**mysql**

```
check process mysql with pidfile /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
  group database
  start program = "/etc/init.d/mysql start" with timeout 60 seconds
  stop program = "/etc/init.d/mysql stop"
```

**ssh**

```
check process sshd with pidfile /var/run/sshd.pid
  start program "/etc/init.d/ssh start"
  stop program "/etc/init.d/ssh stop"
```

Comment: Show the config files.

Comment: Did you see any error in monit's log files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally commented out the following line on monitrc:

```
include /etc/monit/conf.d/*
```